# What can i do to decrease the completing time and make my code go faster at this little program(A program that prints narcissistic numbers))

Tags: c, c99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void){
    clock_t start=clock();
    for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
        long long multi=(long long)pow(10,i-1);
        long long control_multi=(long long)pow(10,i);
        for(long long a=1*multi;a<=control_multi;a++){
            long long armstrong_copy=0;
            for(long long a_copy=a;a_copy;a_copy/=10){
                armstrong_copy+=(long long)pow(a_copy%10,i);
            }
            if(a==armstrong_copy){
                printf("%lld\n",a);
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end=clock();

    printf("%f",(double )(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

It takes 15 minutes to run and complete this program and I dont know how to decrease it to seconds and this program supposed to print narcissistic numbers up to and including the numbers that have 10 digits

Comment: For the benefit of readers, please define "narcissistic number" with the definition you are using. Many readers will not know the definition of this term off the top of their head.

Comment: LonelyProgrammer, `(long long)pow(a_copy%10,i)` --> not necessary to use floating point functions for an integer problem.  Re-think how to do this using only integer math and _not_ performing a power function (hint the power is 10x greater than the pervious `i` iteration)

Comment: This is a duplicate. Long story short, the approach that saves a lot of time is to generate the numbers with the properties that you want, rather than checking candidates to see if they fit.